# python np.dot vectorization

Tags: python, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to get rid of some `for` loops when multiplying matrices. `aa` represents a `3x3` transformation matrix, `bb` represents point coords `nx3`, where `n` is the number of points.

With:

```
aa = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
bb = np.matrix([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])

np.tile(aa,(3,1))*bb.ravel().T
```

I get:

```
ValueError: shapes (9,3) and (9,1) not aligned: 3(dim 1) != 9 (dim 0)
```

Expected output in this case would be **long** column matrix `[[6],[6],[6],[12],[12],[12],[18],[18],[18]]`. Which final shape should be in this case `3x3`: `[[6,6,6],[12,12,12],[18,18,18]]`.

**Edit:** going away from generalized description.
There is `n` number of points, and only one `3x3` matrix.Its a vectorization problem of something like:

```
points = bb
T = aa
pointsNewPos = []

for point in points:
    pointNewPosition = T*point.T
    pointsNewPos.append(pointNewPosition.T)
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, note that `matrix` is pretty much considered deprecated and they encourage you to move to a multidimensional `ndarray`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, didnt know that. Expected output is the same as if you would use for loop. In this case it would be long column matrix [[6],[6],[6],[12],[12],[12],[18],[18],[18]]. Which final shape should be 3x3: [[6,6,6],[12,12,12],[18,18,18]].  Good point on the what the result should look like, Im adding this to the question.

Comment: @ForceBru I thought that for matrices the "*" operator == np.dot.

Comment: @c4da, right, I somehow didn't notice these are actually `np.matrix`, not `ndarray`, oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This at least gives the output that you want in this case. Hard to make sure that it's general without more information.

```
import numpy as np

aa = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
bb = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]])

result = b.dot(aa.T)
```

Comment: If len(aa) != len(bb) then it seems that it doesnt work. As I wrote in the question, there is only one transformation matrix and you could have **n** points.

Comment: @c4da Could you add the expected output of an example where len(aa) != len(bb). It is not very clear what you want from your OP.

Comment: @ user2653663 Ok, I have added more specific description of the problem.

Comment: @c4da Updated the answer. I hope that this is what you need.t

Comment: Thanks it seems to work, Im marking it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [np.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) which lets you do matrix multiplications using arbitrary dimensions of the input matrices.

Assuming you want to use each row of `bb` as a column vector and left multiply it (in row major fashion) by `aa` then give this a whirl:

```
cc = np.einsum('ij,kj -> ki', bb, aa)
```